# Performance issue with many elements retrieving data from store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have performance issues when I render many components and they all need data from the redux store. What could I do to fix this ?

I'm working on a desktop application that looks like a picture editor using electronJs and reactJs.

My redux store looks like this:

```js
store = {
    palettes: {
        palette1: [
            {r: 255, g:   0, b:   0, a: 255},
            {r:   0, g: 255, b:   0, a: 255},
            {r:   0, g:   0, b: 255, a: 255}
        ],
        palette2: [ ... ]
    },
    pictures: {
        picture1: {
            palette: "palette1",
            pixels: [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2 ...]
        }
    }
}
```

My components

```js
class Picture extends Component {
    render = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                {Array(1024).fill(0).map((_, index) =>
                  <Pixel index={index} pictureName={this.props.name} />
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```js
class Pixel extends Component {
    render = () => {
        return (
            <div
              style={{
                width: 2,
                height: 2,
                backgroundColor: this.props.color
              }}
              onClick={/*change this pixel color and dispatch*/}
            >
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    let colorIndex = state.pictures[ownProps.pictureName].pixels[ownProps.index]
    let paletteName = state.pictures[ownProps.pictureName].palette
    let color = state.palettes[paletteName][colorIndex]
    return {
        color: getRGBA(color)
    }
}
```

Helper function

```js
export const getRGBA = ({ r, g, b, a }) => {
  return `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${a / 255})`
}
```

Pictures are a bit like indexed color PNG.

Rendering 1024 Pixels takes way too much time.

On my first try, I retrieved all data I need in Picture and give directly the color to the Pixels. But when I modify on pixel then it rerenders all the Pixels, which is time consuming.

Using a correct selector using `reselect` or even `re-reselect` could fix it ? (I don't really know how to do it properly)

I also tried to memoize `getRGBA` but this function should not be time consuming.

Comment: Rendering 1024 divs will have a performance impact no matter how you look at it. Rendering through react where you add events to it and doing some state management etc, its going to be even slower. Try using Canvas for what you are trying to do

Comment: You could have the palette in the Picture component, then for each `Pixel` incorporate the `color` prop into the `key`. Should mean that if that pixel's color doesn't change, it won't re-render. Also convert `Pixel` into a functional component, it doesn't need to be a class component, they have unnecessary overhead in this case. But as @ConstantinChirila said, rendering and re-rendering over a thousand elements is never gonna be super quick.

Comment: Ok I will take a look on Canvas, I don't know how it works, but it could be a solution.

Comment: I can't have the palette in the Picture because a palette could be shared between Pictures. Or maybe I should duplicate the data in the store when I populate the store, on startup?